# Tracing caller location in iphone xcode

Tags: iphone, call, trace

Is there any way to Trace a phone call in iphone, like when someone call on my iphone then i am able to check the caller's location while my iphone is ringing or after picking up that call.

Any reference to source code will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I would be very surpried unless they are signed into soething like 4 square and you link the phonenumber to their 4 square account in your phonebook

Comment: No, there is no way for tracing caller location.